# How to make question related to math of an investment on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've edited [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/203446/5886) to try and make it more on topic.

Please let me know if this is now on topic or if not, what the outstanding issues might be?

Comment: And it took you only two and a half years!